# Complex plane Riemann sphere equivalent metrics?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Define $d(z_1, z_2) = |z_1 - z_2|$ and $d_\infty(z_1,z_2) = \frac{2|z_1 - z_2|}{\sqrt{1+|z_1|^2}\sqrt{1+|z_2|^2}}$. How to show the following statement?

For every $a \in C$ and $r > 0$, there exists $\rho > 0$ such that Ball $B_\infty(a;\rho) \subset B(a,r)$?

I can show it is true for any $|z| \leq M$, but what if $M \rightarrow \infty$? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the complex plane, every point $z$ satisfies $|z|\leq M$ for some $M$. You don't have to worry about infinity because it's not there. This problem seems to be saying that the metric on the complex plane is equivalen to a metric on a subset of the Riemann sphere, and not the whole sphere.